# How to display data from code igniter model with AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My `Codeigniter` site has side panel and when i click or select any options in side panel appropriate content will appear to the main panel.

Home page `URL` is `http://localhost/main/userinfo/allusers`
When i click female button `URL` is `http://localhost/main/userinfo/female`

[image]
i have following output when i made the Ajax request. Where i did the mistake?
[image]

Controller(main.php)

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();           
    $this->load->model('userinfo_model'); 
}
public function index() {}   
public function userinfo($gender) {
    $this->load->view('home/inc/header_view');        
    $usermain_data['user_info'] = $this->userinfo_model->get_data($gender);
    $this->load->view('home/main_view', $usermain_data);
}
```

Model(userinfo_model.php)

```
class Userinfo_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct() {
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}
function get_data($gender) {      
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    if($gender == 'female'){
        $this->db->where('gender', 0); 
    }
    elseif($gender == 'male'){
        $this->db->where('gender', 1); 
    }
    elseif($gender == 'allusers'){
        $gNames = array(0, 1);             
        $this->db->where_in('gender', $gNames);
    } 
    else {
        redirect(base_url() . 'main/userinfo/allusers');
    }
    $query = $this->db->get('tble_userinfo');
    //return $query->result();
    echo(json_encode($query->result())); 
}}
```

View(main_view.php)

```
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 side_menu">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default gender-label" id="lbl-female" onclick="displayfemale()">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off">
                <span>Female</span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default gender-label" id="lbl-male" onclick="displaymale()">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
                <span>Male</span>
            </label>
        </div> <br> <br> 
        <label class="label nav-label">Age</label>
        <select class="btn nav-age-select" id="ageSelect1" autocomplete="off">
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>       
            <option value="21"  selected="selected">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>       
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>

        </select>
        <label class="label nav-label label-to">To</label>
        <select class="btn nav-age-select" id="ageSelect2" autocomplete="off">
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>       
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>       
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 main-body">
        <div id="userdata">
            <?php
            //foreach ($user_info as $info) {
                //confuse of adding date here with ajax
                //echo $info->content . '<br />' . $info->added_date .'<br />'; 
            //}
            ?>
        </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ajaxUrl     = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/userinfo';        
    var gender      = 'allusers'; // defual 1 for female and male both together

    getAjax(ajaxUrl, gender); 

    $("#lbl-female").click(function () {   
        gender = 'female';
        getAjax(ajaxUrl, gender);  
    });
    $("#lbl-male").click(function () {   
        gender = 'male';
        getAjax(ajaxUrl, gender);  
    });
});     
function getAjax(ajaxUrl, gender){       
    ajaxUrl = ajaxUrl + '/' + gender;                
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (retdata) { 
            $("#userdata").html('');                 
            if(retdata.hasOwnProperty("error")){
                $("#userdata").html('<div">' + retdata.msg + '</div>');  
            }  
            else{    
                $.each(retdata, function(i){    
                    $("#userdata").append(retdata[i].content + '<br>');                       
                });                         
            }

        }
    });          
}
```

Comment: in `userinfo` output should be `echo json_encode()`

Comment: @Spartan i'm sorry & i did(updated the code) as you said. I get only array output. no html or css. i'm confuse of appending data on `DIV` #userdata

Comment: pass ajax to get data only. Not entire template on it

Comment: @Spartan im sorry i couldn't get your point. you meant, my ajax request is wrong. can you please find the issue on my code.

Comment: Should the initial view be "all users"?

Comment: @DFriend Yes (localhost/main/userinfo/allusers). when click female button  url should change to `localhost/main/userinfo/female`. same idea for male.

Comment: You are not sending any data in your AJAX request. I think you should pass your selected gender value along with the request

Comment: I have an answer for you but it will take some time to finish.

Comment: @DFriend sure and please comment about my method is secure or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer will have `main` load both genders initially. Rather than use several gender specific URLs the gender buttons will return the html of the selected gender and dynamically change the html of the page.

main_view.php (with Javascript included)

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 side_menu">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default gender-label" id="lbl-female">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off">
          <span>Female</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default gender-label" id="lbl-male">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
          <span>Male</span>
        </label>
      </div> <br> <br> 
      <label class="label nav-label">Age</label>
      <select class="btn nav-age-select" id="ageSelect1" autocomplete="off">
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>       
        <option value="21"  selected="selected">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>       
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>

      </select>
      <label class="label nav-label label-to">To</label>
      <select class="btn nav-age-select" id="ageSelect2" autocomplete="off">
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>       
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>       
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 main-body">
      <div id="userdata">
        <?php
        foreach($user_info as $info)
        {
          echo $info->content.'<br />'.$info->added_date.'<br />';
        }
        ?>
      </div>         
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var ajaxUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/userinfo';

  $("#lbl-female").click(function () {
    getAjax(ajaxUrl, 'female');
  });
  $("#lbl-male").click(function () {
    getAjax(ajaxUrl, 'male');
  });
});
function getAjax(URL, gender) {
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    data: {gender: gender},
    dataType: "html",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (retdata) {
      $("#userdata").html(retdata);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Note that in the `$.ajax` options with the line

```
data: {gender: gender},
```

we are "posting" data to the controller which will be retrieved by using `$this->input->post("gender");` in the AJAX response function.

Models should not do anything but return data for a controller to use. It is the controller's job to determine what happens based on the data returned. So the `redirect()` call has been removed.

Userinfo_model.php

```
class Userinfo_model extends CI_Model
{
  function __construct()
  {
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
  }

  // Note the default value for argument $gender. 
  // This means you do not have to pass an argument.
  // If you don't pass one, then !empty($gender) === FALSE
  function get_data($gender = NULL)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');

    //select based on gender. 
    //If no $gender then a "where" clause is not needed and both genders are selected
    if(!empty($gender)) 
    //an argument was provided
    {
      if($gender == 'female')
      {
        $this->db->where('gender', 0);
      }
      else
      {
        $this->db->where('gender', 1);
      }
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('tble_userinfo');
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

Finally, we get to the controller. `index()` will display both genders by calling `get_data()` without passing an argument to the model. After that the AJAX responder `userinfo()` will return html of the desired gender to the ajax `success` function. The `success` function will replace the existing html with the new html echoed from `userinfo()`.

```
class Main extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('userinfo_model');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $usermain_data['user_info'] = $this->userinfo_model->get_data();
    $this->load
        ->view('home/inc/header_view')
        ->view('home/main_view', $usermain_data);
  }

  //Only used to respond to an AJAX request
  public function userinfo()
  {
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');

    if(empty($gender))
    {
      $out =  "No Users Found";
    }
    else
    {
      $user_info = $this->userinfo_model->get_data($gender);
      $out = "";

      foreach($user_info as $info)
      {
        $out .= $info->content.'<br />'.$info->added_date.'<br />';
      }
    }
    echo $out;
  }

}
```

This seems reasonably secure so far. The only user input is the gender value. (Never trust user input) Should someone try to pass a value other than the string "female" the database will return only the males info. No user input is presented directly to the database so I don't see any vulnerabilities.

Comment: `window.history.pushState()` will not be useful as the dynamically generated html is not part of the URL. Your requirement to share the URL probably means you have to abandon the dynamic html and turn the buttons into links (e.g.  <a href...> ) styled to look like buttons. Then you would use separate male and female controller functions to retrieve the desired set of users. The model in my answer could be used as is for that.